# Can't Deserialize an Array of Abstract classes using XmlSerializer in .Net

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing, xsd, deserialization

I'm trying to create an object model from an XML file I was given. I obtained the .xsd for the format and used xsd.exe to generate classes to use for the object model. I use the following code to run the deserialization:

```
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(tDefinitions))
Dim xmlStream As New StreamReader("c:\bpmn\bpmn.xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
Dim document As tDefinitions = CType(serializer.Deserialize(xmlStream), tDefinitions)
```

The defintion of tDefinitions is as follows:

```
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038"), _
 System.SerializableAttribute(), _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute([Namespace]:="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("definitions", [Namespace]:="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL", IsNullable:=False)> _
Partial Public Class tDefinitions

    Private importField() As tImport

    Private extensionField() As tExtension

    Private rootElementField() As tRootElement

    Private bPMNDiagramField() As BPMNDiagram

'... removed code for brevity

    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("rootElement")> _
    Public Property rootElement() As tRootElement()
        Get
            Return Me.rootElementField
        End Get
        Set(value As tRootElement())
            Me.rootElementField = value
        End Set
    End Property

'... removed code for brevity
```

When I run the code it successfully creates a tDefinitions object. However, only the fields that are arrays of concrete types get populated. rootElementField() ends up being Nothing as tRootElement is an abstract class type. If I create arrays of all the specific types that inherit tRootElement, those arrays do get populated. Here is the defintion of tRootElement:

```
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(tSignal)), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(tResource)), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(tPartnerRole)), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(tPartnerEntity)), _
'Many more types removed for brevity
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(GetType(tGlobalBusinessRuleTask)), _
 System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038"), _
 System.SerializableAttribute(), _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute([Namespace]:="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("rootElement", [Namespace]:="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL", IsNullable:=False)> _
Partial Public MustInherit Class tRootElement
    Inherits tBaseElement
End Class
```

Any ideas as to what I can do to make this work? I would consider writing my own parser except the xml schema is extremely large and it could take me weeks of grunt work.

Comment: you have `tRootElement` defined as a base class but seem to be using it as a property Type? is that right?

Comment: Thanks for the fast response @Plutonix. I don't think I'm using it as a PropertyType. Here is a example of the xml:    <definitions  exporterVersion="1">
 <collaboration id="collaboration-_8"></collaboration></definitions>  - note that collaboration is a descendant of rootElement

Comment: I got to the bottom of the problem. It's because "Public Property rootElement() As tRootElement()" needs to have XMLIncludeAttributes for all of the possible child classes that could belong in that collection. I did not include a particular xsd file, which resulted in these tags not being created when I ran the XSD utility.